# When is appropriate time to persist configuration?

Tags: c#, xml, configuration, xml-serialization

I have the following problem: I save(xml serialize) my configuration(very large list of object) on app exit, main form closing , but sometimes OS (win 7) on some comps terminates my app before the save is finished. So I'm asking when is the best time to do this , I thought maybe on main form minimize,but that to conditional(user maybe will never minimize the app).

Comment: is this a desktop app? What about an embedded database instead of putting everything in config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WPF Only**

have you tried putting it in your application class? There is an override that fires on application exit. The method below takes 10 seconds to complete it's task and also makes the user click the OK button on the messagebox before the application closes.

this will not work if you're saving your config in another thread though, it'll just exit the application.

App.xaml.cs

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            MessageBox.Show("done");
            base.OnExit(e);
        }
    }
```

**Win Forms**

in Winforms applications you can hook on to the ApplicationExit event and save your config there.

```
Application.ApplicationExit += new EventHandler(Application_ApplicationExit);
static void Application_ApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: I'm very sorry, I have clicked the XML tag instead of XAML, this answer is specific only to a WPF application (though the comment about threading is still valid in winforms)

Comment: I've added a winforms solution as well.